# Trying to compare the contents of two excel files and save the difference by python

Tags: excel, pandas, compare, difference, difflib

I have two excel files containing multiple lines of excel from a datalogger, and I need to compare the two files with 3 similar columns (anum,bnum,date,time) but with different column durations, and then save the difference into a third excel file.

***excel file 1:

```
anum            bnum duration   date     time
02473082424 0969755655  12  2018-08-04  10:53:04
02473082424 02435543470 17  2018-08-04  10:53:04
02473082424 01653559999 19  2018-08-04  10:53:06
02473082424 02437633476 63  2018-08-04  10:52:46
02473082424 02432262638 23  2018-08-04  10:53:26
02473082424 02435537928 40  2018-08-04  10:53:18
02473082424 0936467084  20  2018-08-04  10:53:42
```

***excel file 2:

```
   anum       bnum   duration   date     time
    02473082424 0969755655  16  2018-08-04  10:53:04
    02473082424 02435543470 17  2018-08-04  10:53:04
    02473082424 01653559999 23  2018-08-04  10:53:06
    02473082424 02437633476 63  2018-08-04  10:52:46
    02473082424 02432262638 23  2018-08-04  10:53:26
    02473082424 02435537928 10  2018-08-04  10:53:18
    02473082424 0936467084  20  2018-08-04  10:53:42
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first read both excel files using [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)
into two dataframes df1 and df2 Then :

```
df1.rename(columns={'duration':'duration1'},inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={'duration':'duration2'},inplace=True)
df=df1.merge(df2)
df['duration']=df['duration2']-df['duration1']
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file_3)
df[['anum','bnum','duration','date','time']].to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
```